# Get file information from multiple files listed inside a text file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, filelist

I have multiple file listed in `files.txt`, these files are located in different folders.  I need to get the files information, such as date modified and size, exported to a `.txt` or `.csv` file.

Is there a command in Windows? or how can I put it in a batch file or powershell script?

`files.txt` content:

```
c:\windows\system32\file1.dll
c:\windows\temp\file2.dll
c:\program files\file3.exe
and so on....
```

**Edit**

I tried this in a batch file, but the output looks awful:

```
@echo off
dir c:\windows\system32\file1.dll >>filelist.txt
dir c:\windows\temp\file2.dll >>filelist.txt
dir c:\program files\file3.exe >>filelist.txt
```

Comment: Please take a look at [tour], [ask] and [mcve].
What have you tried so far? It would be nice if you show some effort.

Comment: Also, a quick tip: Use Powershell, take a look at `Get-Content` and `Get-Item`.

Comment: I have tried: this on a batch file, although the output looks awful.
@echo off
dir c:\windows\system32\file1.dll >>filelist.txt
dir c:\windows\temp\file2.dll >>filelist.txt
dir c:\program files\file3.exe >>filelist.txt

Comment: Edit your question and post the code you tried there. Also what do you mean with "looks awful". What do you want?

Comment: Enter `DIR /?` at your Command Prompt and read the usage information output. Then test the command using its various options, _(what you've learned)_, on some individual files and directories. Once you've done that and you're comfortable with that command, enter `FOR /?` at the Command Prompt, and begin reading again. _This isn't a give me the code site, nor is it a tutorial site, please learn how to use the commands, write your code, and if you have an issue with it, add it to your question by editing and formatting it accordingly._

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\file.txt" | where {Test-Path $_} | %{Get-Item $_} | select FullName, LastWriteTime
```

Explication:

```
Test-Path : for test if file exist
Get-Item : for take file information
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should downvote this, edit this or just comment _code-only, please clarify..._ While this answer is technically good, it has at least 2 typos, no description and really shows not more effort than the OPs question... (Oh and could fit in a comment)

Answer (score 0):

A batch solution,

- getting file location from the environment variable temp and
- reporting nonexistent files to the console

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.cmd
@Echo off
set "FileIn=%temp%\file.txt"
set "FileOut=%temp%\file.csv"

( Echo "FileName","Size","LastWriteTime"
  For /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%FileIn%") do (
    If Exist "%%A" (
      For %%B in ("%%A") Do Echo "%%~fB","%%~zB","%%~tB"
    ) else (
      >CON: Echo File %%A doesn't exist
    )
  )
) > "%FileOut%"
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_51397282.cmd
File blabla blub doesn't exist

> type %temp%\file.csv
"FileName","Size","LastWriteTime"
"Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.cmd","370","2018-07-19 14:26"
"Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.ps1","354","2018-07-19 14:19"
"Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51416162.ps1","473","2018-07-19 14:03"
```

And a PowerShell solution doing very similar.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.ps1
$FileIn  = "$($Env:temp)\file.txt"
$FileOut = "$($Env:temp)\file.csv"

$Csv = Get-Content $FileIn | ForEach-Object {
    If (Test-Path $_) {
        Get-Item $_ | Select-Object FullName,Length,LastWriteTime
  } Else {
    Write-Host ("File {0} doesn't exist!" -f $_)
  }
}
$Csv
$Csv| Export-Csv $FileOut -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SO_51397282.ps1
File blabla blub doesn't exist!

FullName                           Length LastWriteTime
--------                           ------ -------------
Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.cmd    370 2018-07-19 14:26:21
Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.ps1    372 2018-07-19 14:30:02
Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51416162.ps1    473 2018-07-19 14:03:31

> type $env:tmp\file.csv
"FullName","Length","LastWriteTime"
"Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.cmd","370","2018-07-19 14:26:21"
"Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51397282.ps1","372","2018-07-19 14:30:02"
"Q:\Test\2018\07\19\SO_51416162.ps1","473","2018-07-19 14:03:31"
```